# VBA telnet using plink (Putty's commandline) - send command to plink.exe

Tags: excel, vba, putty, plink

I want to:

1. Connect to some machine using VBA as a TCP/IP client.
2. Send it a command - say "help" + vbcrlf
3. Capture the reply into the clipboard or a file, both of which I can then just paste into the worksheet
4. This part is really confounding me - with both .run and .exec, I can't figure out how to send "help" + carriage return. I can open the shell window, but can't get StdIn to send a command to plink.exe.

I haven't gotten far:

```
Sub Test1()

    Const TARGET_HOST = "192.168.0.2 -P 24" ' Some proprietary telnet port 
    Const PLINKPATH = "C:\program files\putty\plink.exe"

    Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cmd = """C:\program files\putty\plink.exe"" -telnet " & TARGET_HOST

    sh.Run cmd & " | clip", 1, True

End Sub
```

If this method is not the correct method to send a command to plink.exe, what other methods could be used without having to use the winsock method which is very difficult to maintain moving forward.

Comment: Isn't there a command you can send to the server to close the session? Like `exit`?

Comment: I think exit only works if you are using telnet from cmd. Anyhow this is just a starting point for a whole bunch of other stuff I'd like to be able to do - it's just really frustrating I can't get past this point. I've spent hours researching on this - I've seen a good example on how to capture a reply from cmd - like ipconfig, for example, but I just can't seem to get this to work with plink.

Comment: *"I think exit only works if you are using telnet from cmd"* - Why do you think so? Why would `exit` behave differently in your code? + I do not understand the rest of your comment. So far, your only problem you told us about it closing of the connection of the hidden Plink instance.

Comment: How would you send the exit command?

In the example above - all I am getting is a cmd window showing I have successfully connected to whatever device. 

I can't figure out how to (1) send a command to that shell, (2) close the window. How do you send "exit"? sh.Run "exit" does not work - nor does manually typing the word exit, since the shell window that is opened is now a connection to the device. If I go to the shell window, and type exit - that just returns an error because the other device does not support the command exit.

Comment: I should clarify this is not a normal telnet connection to another PC - this is a tcp client session with any product that supports a tcp connection. I was hoping to make an Excel sheet where I could specify port numbers and what commands to send on the sheet itself.

Comment: Sending a command is a task you have to solve anyway. So if you want be able to send "help" or any other command, you must be able to send "exit". -- So again, do your devices have a command to close a session or not?

Comment: I haven't worked out how to send "help" either. The session is opened by plink, and as far as I know it is up to plink to close the session - the third party devices do not have a command to close plink that I am aware of.

Comment: OK, then you have two separate problems: 1) Executing commands in Plink. 2) Closing (hidden) Plink automatically. -- Please ask them separately.

Comment: Ok, edited as suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple input redirection. You actually already redirect the output with `| clip`. Similarly to redirect also the input, do:

```
"echo help | " & cmd & " | clip"
```

---

See also [How to execute remote command using PuTTY over Telnet](https://superuser.com/q/914643/213663).